# Perl OOP cant see new method

Tags: perl

Started to learn Perl, trying OOP, created main program and package. While trying to create object of class package receive an error in main file. Calling a new method inside package works.

Main.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
BEGIN { unshift @INC , '.';}
use Stack01Lib;

print "Hello, World!\n";

my @stack = new Stack01Lib();
```

Stack01Lib.pm

```
  package Stack01Lib;

  use strict; 
  use warnings;

  sub new {
    my($class) = shift;
    my $self = { };

    bless $self, $class;

    return $self;
  }

1;  

print "Loaded\n";
```

After compilation

```
Can't locate object method "new" via package "Stack01Lib" (perhaps you forgot to load "Stack01Lib"?) at D:\Projects\perl\hello\Main.pl line 26.
Loaded
Hello, World!
```

Comment: Tip: `new Stack01Lib()` is better written as `Stack01Lib->new()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not loading the file you showed, possibly because of this bug:

```perl
BEGIN { unshift @INC , '.';}
```

Relative paths in `@INC` are relative to the current work directory. You want script's directory, so it should be

```perl
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
BEGIN { unshift @INC, $RealBin; }
```

Simpler:

```perl
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;
```

The code you posted is otherwise fine. It does not result in the error you posted.

Comment: Script in same directory, and main file after compilation prints Loaded from package so i consider it has loaded correctly.

Comment: I didn't say you didn't load a module; I said you didn't load the one you posted. Did you fix the bug?

Comment: No, it doesn't work, same error with this variant.

Comment: What I said stands though; the code you posted is otherwise fine.

Comment: It would seem you had run it yourself and it works. Then error not in code, which is worse. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Make sure the `package`, `use` and file name match exactly, case and all.

Comment: Yes, it turned out to be the problem, by a couple of renamings it was solved. But i am sure the names matched previously, and now it callable even when package and file name are different. Thank you!

Comment: @valentine you're doing something wrong if they're different